# camel-activemq brokerURL parameter not recognized in camel route

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to use camel-activemq dependency and setting up a service that is listening to activemq queue. When i try to set the connection in the camel route exclusively, the endpoint i am using is :

"activemq:mailq?username=admin&password=password&trustAllPackages=true&concurrentConsumers=10&exchangePattern=InOnly&maxConcurrentConsumers=20&brokerURL=tcp://mail-broker-queue-pod:61616"

My problem is that the activemq dependency is defualting to the failover "localhost:61616" because it does not recoginze the brokerURL parameter.

I am trying to connect to a queue that is deployed on an openshift server. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`brokerURL` is not a parameter of the ActiveMQ component. If you would like to specify the `brokerURL` then you have to add the `activemq` component to the CamelContext like the following ([source](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-camel/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/camel/component/ActiveMQRouteTest.java#L63)):

```
camelContext.addComponent("activemq", activeMQComponent("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false"));
```

Example if you use Spring ([source](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html#ActiveMQ-ConfiguringtheConnectionFactoryusingSpringXML)):

```
@Bean(name = "activemq")
public ActiveMQComponent createActiveMQComponent() {
    return ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("tcp://localhost:61616"); // configure brokerURL here
}
```

Comment: yes i am able to add the activemq component through java code by setting up a connection factory. However, I would like to just configure and listen to the remote queue just by using the endpoint. Any idea the correcto parameters to connect to an activemq queue by just using the endpoint? Thanks

Comment: As answered above, this is not possible. However if you are using Camel with Spring Boot you can configure the broker url in the spring boot application.properties/yaml file.

Comment: You saved my bacon . I was unable to understand as to why my camel route is defaulting to failover - tcp://localhost:61616 even after I do a DIT deployment in an AWS environment . Then after looking at your post , I realized that camel-activemq requires an activemqcomponent to be set up , which will  explicitly set connectionfactory via  external broker . Upvoted .